# output to a file in script directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, posix

This probably quite basic but I have spent whole day finding an answer without much success.

I have an executable script that resides in `~/Desktop/shell/myScript.sh`

I want a single line command to run this script from my terminal that outputs to a new directory in same directory where the script is located no matter what my present working directory is.

I was using:

```
mkdir -p tmp && 
  ./Desktop/shell/myScript.sh|grep '18x18'|cut -d":" -f1 > tmp/myList.txt
```

But it creates new directory in present working directory and not on the target location.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no way to run `mkdir -p tmp && somescript` and have `somescript` affect where the directory is created. You could rewrite the script so that you can run `somescript tmp/myList.txt`, and have the script [look up its directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in) and write the file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Lets ignore the mkdir part and just output in the script directory and not the present working directory, what are my options?

Comment: There is similarly no way to run `somescript > tmp/myList.txt` and have `somescript` affect where the file is written. As mentioned, you can rewrite the script so that you can run `somescript tmp/myList.txt`, and then put e.g. `echo text > "/my/dir/$1"` in the script to write to `/my/dir/tmp/myList.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it in one line if you pre-define a variable:

```
export LOC=$HOME/Desktop/shell
```

Then you can say

```
mkdir -p $LOC/tmp && $LOC/myScript.sh | grep '18x18' | cut -d":" -f1 > $LOC/tmp/myList.txt
```

But if you're doing this repeatedly it might be better long-term to wrap `myScript.sh` so that it creates the directory, and redirects the output, for you. The `grep` and `cut` parameters, as well as the output file name, would be passed as command-line arguments and options to the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SCRIPTDIR="./Desktop/shell/" ; mkdir "$SCRIPTDIR/tmp" ; "$SCRIPTDIR/myScript.sh" | grep '18x18' | cut -d ":" -f 1 > "$SCRIPTDIR/tmp/myList.txt"
```

In your case you have to give the path to the script anyway.  If you put the script in the path where it is automatically searched,  e.g. `$HOME/bin`, and you can just type `myScript.sh` without the directory prefix,  you can use `SCRIPTDIR=$( dirname $( which myScript.sh ) )`.

Mixing directories with binaries and data files is usually a bad idea.  For temporary files `/tmp` is the place to go.  Consider that your script might become famous and get installed by the administrator in `/usr/bin` and run by several people at the same time.  For this reason, try to think [`mktemp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982911/creating-temporary-files-in-bash).

Answer (score 1):

**YOUR SCRIPT CAN DO THIS FOR YOU WITH SOME CODES**

Instead of doing this manually from the command line and who knows where you will move your script and put it. add the following codes

**[1] Find your script directory location using dirname**

```
script_directory=`dirname $0`
```

The above code will find your script directory and save it in a variable.

**[2] Create your "tmp" folder in your script directory**

```
mkdir "$script_directory/tmp 2> /dev/null"
```

The above code will make a directory called "tmp" in your script directory. If the directory exist, mkdir will not overwrite any existing directory using this command line and gave an error. I hide all errors by "2> /dev/null"

**[3] Open your script and modify it using "cut" and then redirect the output to a new file**

```
cat "$0"|grep '18x18'|cut -d":" -f1 > "$script_directory"/tmp/myList.txt
```