# creating a temporary file in memory and using it as input file of a command

Tags: bash

There is a command pdflatex, which I want to use in my bash script. It takes as input a filename on which content it will work.

Now I have an algorithms that looks as follows:

```
for stuff in list of stuff; do
  echo "${stuff}" > /tmp/tmpStuff
  pdflatex /tmp/tmpStuff
done
```

Now this works as expected. But I was thinking I could speed that up by doing less disk I/O(as > redirection writes to a file). I wish I could write something like `echo "$stuff" | pdflatex /tmp/tmpStuff` but pdflatex uses a file and not stdin as its input. Is there any way of keeping `"$stuff"` in memory and passing it to pdflatex as a sort of file?

TLDR: I would be happy if I could create a temporary file which could be named and be in memory.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use process substitution for this:

```
pdflatex <(echo "$stuff")
```

From the Bash Reference Manual:

> [**3.5.6 Process Substitution**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)
>
> Process substitution is supported on systems that support named pipes
>   (FIFOs) or the /dev/fd method of naming open files. It takes the form
>   of
>
> ```
> <(list)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> >(list)
> ```
>
> The process list is run with its input or output connected to a FIFO or some file in /dev/fd. The name of this file is passed as an argument to the current command as the result of the expansion. If the
>   `>(list)` form is used, writing to the file will provide input for list. If the `<(list)` form is used, the file passed as an argument should be read to obtain the output of list. Note that no space may appear between the < or > and the left parenthesis, otherwise the construct would be interpreted as a redirection.

And I also wonder if a here-string would make it as well:

```
pdflatex <<< "$stuff"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any way of naming the file resulting file "temporary" file coming from `<(echo "$stuff")` ? I'm wondering that because it seems to cause errors in pdflatex.

Comment: @Simonlbc no, not really. If you want this, you may want to take a look to [mktemp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10983009/1983854).

Comment: if I create a file with mktemp, will the file be in memory?

Comment: @Simonlbc You can check creating a named pipe as explained in [Pseudo files for temporary data](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/63933/40596). However, it seems better to use process substitution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems echo `"$stuff" | pdflatex -jobname outputPdfName`seems to work after all. I tried `pdflatex <<< "$stuff" -jobname outputPdfName` too and it seems to works without errors too, which is nice. So I guess `<<< "$stuff"` is like redirecting a string to stdin, am I right(I'm just genuinely curious)?

Comment: @Simonlbc you are absolutely right :) See [here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) in the Bash manual.

Answer (score 8):

**None** of the presented solutions **is guaranteed to work** on all  possible commands.

Consider `myCommand` below (instead of `pdflatex`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# myCommand
test -f "$1" || { echo "error: Please provide a file"; exit 1; }
echo "The file content is:"$(cat $1)
```

Trying the **existing solutions:**

```sh
./myCommand <(echo "abcdef")
# error: Please provide a file

echo "abcdef" | ./myCommand /dev/stdin
# error: Please provide a file
```

In my Ubuntu **I use** the following approach (utilizing [/dev/shm](https://superuser.com/a/45509) in-memory file storage):

```sh
ramtmp="$(mktemp -p /dev/shm/)"
echo "abcdef" > $ramtmp
./myCommand $ramtmp
# The file content is:abcdef
```

So in **your case** it would be:

```sh
ramtmp="$(mktemp -p /dev/shm/)"
for stuff in list of stuff; do
  echo "${stuff}" > $ramtmp
  pdflatex $ramtmp
done
```

In case pdflatex execution is non-blocking add the first line inside the loop.

**Note that**, I'm not sure how many distributions currently support it. See [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#Support_on_Unix-like_systems):

> Linux distributions based on the 2.6 kernel and later offer `/dev/shm` as **shared memory in the form of a RAM disk**, more specifically as a **world-writable directory** (a directory in which every user of the system can create files) that is **stored in memory**. Both the **RedHat** and **Debian based** distributions **include it** by default. Support for this type of RAM disk is completely optional within the kernel configuration file.[5]

Comment: I've asked a question specifically about something that works in *all* cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67050503/standard-linux-utility-similar-to-bash-process-substitution-to-provide-output-of

Answer (score 7):

Many shells, and Linux as a whole, accept:

```
echo "${stuff}"  | pdflatex /dev/stdin
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm just wondering why you would at the same time use "|" symbol and at the same time precise /dev/stdin is there a reason for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5432899/simonlbc:  /dev/stdin was added just for programs that don't have a specific way to access stdin... your post implies pdflatext is one of them. In the simple case it is also easier than process substitution. Use of the longer name can also be useful, and self documenting, at times. FYI: The other two of the /dev/std* family also exist.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a ramdisk, a filesystem that lives in ram. I always compile my LaTeX on a ramdisk to save disk writes, and also use one for Portage software builds on Gentoo for the same reason.

Here's how you create one:

Linux:
`sudo mkdir /mnt/ramdisk sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=2G ramdisk /mnt/ramdisk`

> feel free to change the mount point to anything. a popular option is /tmp/tmpfs or /tmp/ram

macOS:
`` diskutil erasevolume HFS+ "ramdisk" `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://$((sizeInGB*1024*2048))` ``

> this example will mount on /Volumes/ramdisk
>
> if you wish to use MB replace the end with `ram://$((sizeInMB*2048))`