# Not able to fetch the exit status of a multiple commands (separated by PIPE) which got assigned to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Below is the sample script which i am trying to execute; but it fails to fetch the exit status of `$cmd`; is there any other way to fetch its exit status..!?

```
cmd="curl -mddddddd google.com"
status=$($cmd | wc -l)
echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

I know that, if i replace `status=$($cmd | wc -l)` with `$cmd | wc -l` , i could fetch the exit status of `$cmd` using `PIPESTATUS`. But in my case i have to assign it to a variable (example: status in above case).

Please help me here..!

Regards,
Rohith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to echo the pipe status, you can redirect that to stderr. But you have to do it in the subshell.

```
status=$($cmd | wc -l; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]} >&2)
```

Or you can capture both variables from the subshell using `read`

```
read -rd $'\0' status pstatus <<<$($cmd | wc -l; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]})
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're assigning to the `status` variable is not a status, but what `$cmd | wc -l` pipeline prints to standard output.

Why do you `echo` anyway? Try `realstatus=${PIPESTATUS[0]}`.

---

**EDIT** (After some digging and RTFMing...):

Just this -- `realstatus=${PIPESTATUS[0]}` -- doesn't seem to help, since `$(command_substitution)`, which is in your code, is done *"in a subshell environment"*, while `PIPESTATUS` is about *"the most-recently-executed **foreground** pipeline"*

If what you're trying to do **in this particular case** is to ensure the `curl` (aka `$cmd`) command was succesfull in the pipeline you should probably make use of `pipefail` option ([see here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pipelines)).

Answer (score 2):

If the output of the command is text and not excessively large, the simplest way to get the status of the command is to not use a pipe:

```
cmd_output=$($cmd)
echo "'$cmd' exited with $?"
linecount=$(wc -l <<<"$cmd_output")
echo "'wc' exited with $?"
```

What counts as "excessively large" depends on the system, but I successfully tested the code above with a command that generated 50 megabytes (over one million lines) of output on an old Linux system.

If the output of the command is too big to store in memory, another option is to put it in a temporary file:

```
$cmd >tmpfile
echo "'$cmd' exited with $?"
linecount=$(wc -l <tmpfile)
echo "'wc' exited with $?"
```

You need to be careful when using temporary files though.  See [Creating temporary files in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10982911/4154375) and [How create a temporary file in shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/181937/264812).

Note that, as with the OP's example code, the unquoted `$cmd` in the code examples above is dangerous.  It should not be used in real code.