# How to capture / redirect stdout/stderr from a source command into a variable (in a bash script)?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, subshell

Usually I capture the output via a subshell:
`result="$(command 2>&1)"`

If the command is `source`, the subshell swallows some (all?) changes to the scripts shell's environment.

How can I capture the output of `source` into a variable?

Comment: What is the point of capturing the output of `source`?

Comment: Yes, all changes are lost when the subshell exits (unless there are files written). A subshell is not allowed to alter the parent's environment.

Comment: @oguz ismail: error-handling

Comment: That is usually done using exit statuses of commands.

Comment: @oguz ismail: That is what I do. I also like to log :)

Comment: @Philippe: If I get this right, you'll run into the subshell isolation problem (env vars are lost)

Comment: If you own the script you're sourcing, you could (instead of sourcing it) make it produce a set of assignments like `VAR=value` on standard output (keep standard error for errors and logging only). Then invoke it with `eval "$(bash myscript.sh)"`. This is what pyenv does.

Comment: @oguzismail My reason is because my bashrc sources a script that produces lots of output.  I would redirect to `/dev/null` but then if there is an error I don't see what went wrong.  I want to capture the output and print it only if sourcing the file returned a non-zero code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Surprisingly tricky question!

My first thought was to use a named pipe (`mkfifo(1)`), but those have a finite buffer size, so if the `source`d script fills up the buffer the script would hang. And you can't use a background process to drain the buffer because you want the output in a variable in the original process eventually.

I'm sure there's a way to make it work entirely in memory, but in the end I think a simple and stupid redirect to a temporary file is the most straightforward and robust solution:

```
OUTPUT_FILE=$(mktemp)
source other_script.sh >$OUTPUT_FILE 2>&1
OUTPUT="$(< "$OUTPUT_FILE")"
rm -f "$OUTPUT_FILE"
```

(See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982911/creating-temporary-files-in-bash) and in particular [BashFAQ 062](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/062) for security implications of `mktemp` though.)

Comment: I think this is an nifty, clean solution. I don't mind leaving the RAM for a moment :) I liked it from the beginning, only marked now as 'accepted' to wait for other answers.